# Automatically merging a large number of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had a big dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=
team     workplace    job    employee
a        w1           j1     x
a        w1           j1     y
a        w1           j2     z
b        w1           j1     x
b        w1           j3     t
c        w2           j4     s
c        w2           j5     u
```

I split it into multiple dataframes based on `team`:

```
grouper = [g[1] for g in df.groupby(['team'])
```

I also have a second dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2=
employee    workplace    feedback    question
x           w1           True        q1
x           w1           False       q2
x           w1           True        q2
y           w1           True        q1
y           w1           False       q4
z           w1           False       q1
z           w1           False       q2
z           w1           True        q2
t           w1           False       q3
s           w2           True        q6
s           w2           False       q6
u           w2           True        q6
u           w2           False       q7
```

I know how to add the questions and feedback to a dataframe with teams:

```
grouper0_feedbacks = grouper[0].merge(df2, on=['employee', 'workplace'])
```

But how can I do it for all of them without writing it manually, when there are so many dataframes in `grouper`?

Comment: What about merging first, grouping second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order of operations should working here - first `merge`, then split:

```
df1 = df.merge(df2, on=['employee', 'workplace']) 

grouper0_feedbacks = [g for _, g in df1.groupby(['team'])]
```

If really need it use list comprehension for loop:

```
grouper = [g for _, g in df.groupby(['team'])]
grouper0_feedbacks = [g.merge(df2, on=['employee', 'workplace']) for g in grouper]
```

Comment: Thank you! I only have one trivial question that I'm not sure about: when I split it first (like in my post, but on a huge dataset), the length of grouper was equal to the number of teams that I have. When I merge it first and then split it, then the length of the grouper is much smaller. That means that for some teams no `employee`s were found in `df2`, right? I'm always afraid of losing data when I use `df.merge` haha.